# Referencing column 'follower_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'followers_ibfk_1' are incompatible. What is my mistake?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-8

I'm trying to connect follower_id to users id and all I'm getting is this error. Can anyone help. This is my code:

```
 Schema::create('followers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("user_id");
            $table->foreignId("user_id")->constrainted()->onDelete();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("follower_id");
            $table->foreignId("follower_id")->constrainted()->onDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
            $table->id();
            $table->string("username");
            $table->string("email");
           $table->string("password");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For referencing the `follower_id` to the `users` table as foreign key, try this:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('follower_id');
$table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

---

### WARNING:

The instruction:

```php
$table->foreignId("user_id")->constrainted();
// OR
$table->foreignId("follower_id")->constrainted();
```

Is a shortcut for:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
// OR
$table->unsignedBigInteger('follower_id');
$table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('followers');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints